# Determining the API is RPC or REST

Tags: json, rest, flask

I recently designed a REST API using flask for a sample project. The front end was based on React.JS. But i got a feedback from a colleague that the API is not REST API and its RPC.

The API basically accepts 3 parameters, 2 numbers and a operation ('add','sub','mul','div'). on an end point http://127.0.0.1:5000/calculator
The input JSON will look like:

```
{"value1":"7.1","value2":"8","operator":"mul"}
```

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort
from flask_cors import CORS

APP = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
CORS(APP)  # For cross origin resource sharing
APP.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@APP.route('/calculator', methods=['POST'])
def calculator_operation():

    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    try:
        val1 = float(request.json['value1'])
        val2 = float(request.json['value2'])
        operator = request.json['operator']
        if operator == 'add':
            result = val1 + vla2
        elif operator == 'mul':
            result = val1 * val2
        elif operator == 'sub':
            result = val1 - val2
        elif operator == 'div' and val2 == 0:
            result = 'Cant divide by 0'
        elif operator == 'div':
            result = round((val1 / val2), 2)

        return (jsonify({'result': result}), 200)
    except KeyError:

        abort(400)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.run(debug=True)
```

The code works fine. I would like to know if this is REST or RPC based on the end points and the operation being performed.

EDIT:

Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/calculator",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                value1: arg1,
                value2: arg2,
                operator: this.state.operation
            }),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success:( data ) => {
                this.setState({ result: data.result, argumentStr: data.result });
            },
            error: (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you been looking up on the internet what REST means? What would you say?

Comment: @hek2mgl I did and I am quiet confused. This seems to be restful to me. Adding endpoint to each operation would make additional difficult to maintain if there are more functionalities. Is taking more than 2 values in the input make it RPC ?

Comment: Simple scenario, how does a client "know" or "learn" what a server expects as input upon sending a request to it? Where does the knowledge stem from? Is it some arbitrary documentation the client developer has to go through? --> RPC; is the information provided, like in the Web, in a form and a client just "surfs" through the application via links? --> most likely REST; does it also respect a multitude of media types and content-type negotiation? --> even more likely REST; in all other scenarios --> RPC.

Comment: 2 good sources to start with: [Good introduction video by Stefan Tilkov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM&t=2022s), [Common misconceptions and client-design by Asbjørn Ulsberg](https://nordicapis.com/designing-a-true-rest-state-machine/)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if this is REST or RPC based on the end points and the operation being performed.

How does the client discover what the endpoint is, and what the input json looks like?

On the web, there would be a standard media type that describes forms; the representation of the form would include keys and values, a target URI, and an HTTP method to use.  The processing rules would describe how to take the details of the form, and the values provided by the consumer, and from them construct an HTTP request.

That's REST: doing what we do on the web.

Another REST approach would be to define a [link relation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288), perhaps "http://example.org/calculator", and a media type `application/prs.calculator+json`, and then document that in your context the "http://example.org/calculator" link relation indicates that the target URI responds to POST messages with payload `application/prs.calculator+json`.  This is essentially what [Atom Syndication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) and [Atom Pub](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023).

That's also REST.

Fielding made an interesting comment about [an API he had designed](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/paper-tigers-and-hidden-dragons)

> I should also note that the above is not yet fully RESTful, at least how I use the term. All I have done is described the service interfaces, which is no more than any RPC. In order to make it RESTful, I would need to add hypertext to introduce and define the service, describe how to perform the mapping using forms and/or link templates, and provide code to combine the visualizations in useful ways.

That said, if you are performing GET-with-a-payload, a semantically [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) request with a body, then you are probably trapped in RPC thinking.  Notice that on the web, parameterized reads are done by communicating to the client how to modify the target-uri (for instance, by appending a query string with data encoded according to standardized processing rules).

Answer (score 0):

REST stands for REpresentational State Transfer. Your operation is stateless, therefore there is no state to transfer. Your operation does, however, accept arguments and return a result in the manner of a procedure or function, and it is remote, so Remote Procedure Call would be a good description of what's going on. You are, after all, providing a language-independent way for clients to call your `calculator_operation` procedure.

What's conspicuously missing from your model is server-side data. In general, a REST API provides a way to interact with server-side objects: to query, create, replace, update, or delete. There's no data kept on your server side: it's just an oracle which answers questions. You have the "query" aspect and nothing else.

Comment: Be careful with the word _stateless_. ReST is stateless (on the server side) because all application state is transferred from the client. See: https://restfulapi.net/statelessness/

Comment: As your reference points out, there is more than one kind of state: it distinguishes between *application* state (or session state), which REST avoids, and *resource* state, which REST allows. I would argue that resource state is actually a requirement for REST, or else what does the "state transfer" refer to? This example has no resource state. In fact, it has no resources—no entities which can be operated upon. The values it passes back and forth do not represent entities.

Comment: There is more than one kind of state; but there is only one kind of stateless. :)

Comment: @TFBW Thanks for your answer. I am quiet new to concept of building REST API.I didn't get the part where you mentioned 'stateless there is no state to transfer'. What does that mean? or what can i change to make it a state transfer. The part of create, replace, update, or delete is not there as the application being developed don't perform any operations relevant to these.

Comment: @Vidhu if the application doesn't have any notion of create, replace, update, or delete, then a REST interface is not what you need.

Comment: @TFBW. Sorry I meant to use only read in the given scenario. Does that hold valid? Reading the value of an operation from the backend and returning it. Can we use REST in such a scenario?

Comment: It's a semantic thing. If the requirement is to implement that particular function using REST, then you're getting as close to the concept as can reasonably be expected. If you had been asked to implement that function as RPC over HTTP, you would have fulfilled that request too. Likewise if you'd been asked to implement that function as a microservice. Check. All the above.